# Is the highlighted block of code a computed property?

Tags: swift

```
class Fruit {
    var name: String
    var colour: String
    
    init(name: String, colour: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.colour = colour
    }
    
    **var info: () -> String {
        {
            return "\(self.name) is \(self.colour) in colour"
        }
    }
}**

let fruit = Fruit(name: "apple", colour: "red")
print(fruit.info())
```

Hi,

Can someone explain the type of property of the variable name "info" in the above block of code.

If it is a computed property, can a computed property be written in swift without a get block?

Comment: Yes it is but it's kind of pointless to make it return a function when the signature of the function is `() -> String` since that is the same as declaring it as returning `String` directly. This kind of construction becomes much more meaningful if the function would have a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a computed property, of type `() -> String` (ie. a function with no argument returning a string).

For a computed property returning just a String, which seem to be preferable in your case, you could write :

```swift
var computedProperty: String
{
   get
   {
        return "\(self.name) is \(self.colour) in colour"
   }
}
```

When a property is get-only, you do not need to write the `get{}` block.

```swift
var computedProperty: String
{
   return "\(self.name) is \(self.colour) in colour"
}
```

And if it is only one line, you don't even need to write the `return`.

```swift
var computedProperty: String
{ "\(self.name) is \(self.colour) in colour" }
```

Answer (score 0):

`info` is a read-only computed property. It is declared to have a type that is a closure that takes no parameters and returns a String.

Read-only computed properties do not need an explicit `get`. The `info` property is using a shorthand notation. You can actually get rid of one of the two pairs of curly braces.

It's odd to declare the `info` property to be a closure in this case. It would be much simpler to declare it as:

```
var info: String {
    "\(self.name) is \(self.colour) in colour"
}
```

Then you can use it as normal:

```
print(fruit.info) // <-- Note the lack of () after `info` here.
```

You should read the [Properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html) section of the Swift book. In this case, the [Computed Properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID259) section covers most of your question.

Comment: Yes, the closure does return a string value.

Comment: @Pierre Oops. Corrected.